# Are all public read/write members serialized with XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a handful of public read/write members that are **not** being serialized and I can't figure out why. Reviewing some code, and my root class is marked serializable:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
```

I have a default constructor that initializes 10-15 `string` members. There are about 50 public read/write string members in MyClass with get and set--no explicit serialization attributes are set on any of these. Serialization looks like this:

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
TextWriter twWriter = new StreamWriter(sFileName);
x.Serialize(twWriter, this);
twWriter.Close();
```

only a handful (20-30) of these members are actually seralized to my xml file. what am i missing or misunderstanding about the `XmlSerializer` class?

Comment: what are the types of the fields that are not serialized ? e.g. Hashtables are not serialized by the XmlSerializer

Comment: if they're null, are they skipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force a `null` property to be serialized in the output by setting `IsNullable` to `true` on the `XmlElement` attribute.

```
public class Example
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The `Text` property will now be serialized as `<Text xsi:nil="true" />`.

On a side note the `[Serializable]` attribute is not needed if you are only doing XML serialization.

Answer (score 0):

indeed, they are not serialized if they are null.